# Is there a way to apply conditional formatting to values in a calculation group DAX in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to add conditional formatting to my calculation group DAX so that:

- for values that are above zero, return the value in green
- for values that are zero, return the value in orange
- for values that are below zero, return the value in red

My current calculation group DAX is:

```
 VAR prior_period = CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDMEASURE(),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        TABLE[day],
        [first_day_prior_period],
        [last_day_prior_period]
    )
)

VAR current_period = SELECTEDMEASURE()

VAR PoP = DIVIDE((current_period - prior_period), prior_period)

RETURN PoP
```

I want it so that the returned value (PoP) is returned with colours.

I am aware that in a matrix in PowerBI you can apply conditional formatting for each column but I want to find a way to do so within the calculation group DAX.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. You may want to ask your favorite search engine. There are a handful+ articles about it. Good luck!

Comment: https://www.esbrina-ba.com/calculation-groups-and-conditional-formatting-yes-its-possible/

Answer (score 0):

I do this regularly. Be warned that I usually have to spend more time than I plan getting it right. It's a bit of a pain, but if you need it, here's how to do it.

I start all my CalculationItems off with this boilerplate:

```
SWITCH(TRUE(),
        // _nocg flag, do not modify
        SEARCH( "_nocg", SELECTEDMEASURENAME(), 1, - 1 ) > - 1, SELECTEDMEASURE(),
        //_kpi flag, return the value that gets the conditional formatting you want
        SEARCH( "_kpi", SELECTEDMEASURENAME(), 1, - 1 ) > - 1, BLANK(),
        //normal display value
        SELECTEDMEASURE()
    )
```

The first condition on the SWITCH is for measures which I want to not be affected by the calculation group, I append _nocg to the end of the measure name. An example of when to use this is for dynamic titles on visuals. Calculation groups can wreak havoc on those.

The second condition of the SWITCH is what you're asking for. Create whatever measure you need to and write whatever return you need to in this SWITCH return to get the right KPI value. Just make sure your measure includes "_kpi" so it gets picked up by the SWITCH. If you do not want certain Calculation Items to get conditional formatting, return BLANK(). When you set up Conditional Formatting, use the _kpi measure as the basis for the formatting.

Finally, the last condition does what you would normally do with a calculation group.

By the way, you can do the same type of logic for the format string expression.